# SQL Applying a parameter instead of hard coding

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, business-intelligence

I need a little help, I have a report that I am running that only pulls out certain information based on a number of 'categories' that are hard coded. However, I want to make this as flexible as possible and I want to replace these coded categories with a parameter that can be selected by the user. However when I attempt this it never works for various reasons. The current code is:

```
    SELECT          gcs_allocatedpdaidname AS PDA,
        gcs_consideringapplyingyearname AS 'Intending to Start ITT', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Participants',
        SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND (StatusCode = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Active Participants', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND (StatusCode = 200001) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Completed Participants', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND ((gcs_categoryofparticipant = 7) OR
                            (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 8) OR
                            (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 9) OR
                            (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 10) OR
                            (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 11) OR
                            (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 12)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'On ITT and beyond TOTAL',

        SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND ((StatusCode = 1) OR (StatusCode = 200001)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'On ITT and beyond ACTIVE/COMPLETE'

FROM            FilteredContact
GROUP BY gcs_allocatedpdaidname, gcs_allocatedpdaid, gcs_consideringapplyingyearname
HAVING        (gcs_allocatedpdaidname IN (@PDA)) AND (gcs_consideringapplyingyearname IN (@ITTYear))
ORDER BY PDA, 'Intending to Start ITT'
```

The hard coding I want to replace is the 'gcs_categoryofparticipant', see below:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND
                                ((gcs_categoryofparticipant = 7) OR
                                (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 8) OR
                                (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 9) OR
                                (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 10) OR
                                (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 11) OR
                                (gcs_categoryofparticipant = 12)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'On ITT and beyond TOTAL'
```

I imagine it would be something along the lines of:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND (HAVING (gcs_categoryofparticipant IN (@Category))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'On ITT and beyond TOTAL'
```

This obviously doesnt work but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need HAVING in either the SUM or at the end of the query - the HAVING at the end of the query can be changed to a WHERE, while the SUM can be:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (gcs_allocatedpdaid IS NOT NULL) AND 
              (gcs_ContactType = 1) AND 
              (gcs_categoryofparticipant IN (@Category)) 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
    END) AS 'On ITT and beyond TOTAL'
```

Comment: @ck, you can in reporting services - that's how multi-value parameters work.